# Finding $u(x,y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations

$$
\begin{cases}
(u-y)u_x+u_y=1,\\
u(x,x)=\frac{x}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x_t=u-y\rightarrow x=(u-y)t+f_1(s)\\
y_t=1\rightarrow y=t+f_2(s)\\
u_t=1\rightarrow u=t+f_3(s)
\end{cases}
$$

Using $u(s,s)=\frac{s}{2}$ we get:

$$s=x(0,s)=f_1(s)$$
$$s=y(0,s)=f_2(s)$$
$$\frac{s}{2}=x(0,s)=f_3(s)$$

Therefore:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_t=u-y\rightarrow x=(u-y)t+s\\
y_t=1\rightarrow y=t+s\\
u_t=1\rightarrow u=t+\frac{s}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Checking the Jacobean $$|J|=\frac{-s}{2}-1\neq 0 \iff s\neq -2$$

So next we have to write $u(x,y)$ using:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=(u-y)t+s\\
y=t+s\\
u=t+\frac{s}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

I tried using $t=2u-y$ and $s=2(y-u)$ and more but did not manage to find $u(x,y)$

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is just a string of equations and formulae without so much as a word of explanation.

Comment: I am trying to find $u(x,)$ to return to $u$ as function of x and y

Comment: @newhere. Your calculus is correct. Finally eliminate $s$ and $t$ from the system of three equations $x(s,t),y(s,t),u(s,t)$ in order to get $u(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(u-y)u_x+u_y=1$$
System of characteristic ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange) :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics
$$\frac{dx}{u-y}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{1}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{1}$ :
$$u-y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{u-y}=\frac{dy}{1}$

$\frac{dx}{c_1}=\frac{dy}{1}\quad;\quad \frac{x}{c_1}-y=c_2$
$$\frac{x}{u-y}-y=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\boxed{\frac{x}{u-y}-y=F(u-y)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the boundary condition.

CONDITION : $u(x,x)=\frac{x}{2}$

$\frac{x}{\frac{x}{2}-x}-x=F(\frac{x}{2}-x)$

$-2-x=F(-\frac{x}{2})$

Let $X=-\frac{x}{2}_quad;\quad x=-2X$

$-2-(-2X)=F(X)$
$$F(X)=2X-2$$
So, the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=u-y$

$F(u-y)=2(u-y)-2$

$$\frac{x}{u-y}-y=2(u-y)-2$$
$$(2u-y-2)(u-y)-x=0$$
Solving for $u$ leads to the solution :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac{3y+2\pm\sqrt{(y-2)^2+8x}}{4}}$$
This is consistent with your calculus : $
\begin{cases}
x=(u-y)t+s\\
y=t+s\\
u=t+\frac{s}{2}
\end{cases}
\quad \begin{cases}t=2u-y \\s=2(y-u) \end{cases}$
$$x=(u-y)(2u-y)+2(y-u)$$
$$x=(u-y)(2u-y-2)$$
which is the same as the above equation leading to the same solution.